# Find best crop on image with multiple rois

Tags: image, crop, roi

Summary: What is the best approach to find the best cropping on image with multiple ROIS?

Details:

- we have image size
- we have known ROI score an position on the image
- we have desired output ratio (portrait/landscape/square)
- positive ROI score should be kept
- negative ROI score should be discard

Should i try all possibilities to find the best one or is there any other way to find best crop (score heatmap, object gravity,  statistics...)

Any kind of help is welcome, article, ressource, pseudo code, code

Example of GO code (except implementation of Find method)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
)

type Roi struct {
    image.Rectangle
    Score float64
}

func main() {
    imageBounds := image.Rect(0, 0, 2000, 1000)

    rois := []Roi{
        {Score: 1, Rectangle: image.Rect(10, 10, 20, 20)},
        {Score: -10, Rectangle: image.Rect(400, 400, 600, 600)},
    }

    cropRatio := float64(100) / float64(1000)
    bestCrop := FindBestCrop(imageBounds, cropRatio, rois)
    fmt.Printf("Best cropping was %#v", bestCrop)
}

// positive ROI score should be kept
// negative ROI score should be discard
func FindBestCrop(srcBounds image.Rectangle, cropRatio float64, rois []Roi) image.Rectangle {
    // Solution 1: Scanning by pixel (vertically or horizontally) and compute visible roi score

    // Solution 2: Center crop on roi and compute visible roi score

    // other ???

    return image.Rectangle{}
}
```

Comment: Your code shows some scores, can you use the best score?

Comment: yeah, in fact the best crop was the highest computed score 
The computed score was the sum of all roi visible in the current trying crop